# Prove correctness of DFA ending with ab

Tags: automata, finite-automata, induction

I have the following deterministic finite automaton and I am need to prove correctness of the claim that this automata accepts $\{wab \mid w\in \{a,b\}^*\}$

[image: DFA]

I know that I need to prove by induction on the length of the word but I am not sure how to do the induction step.

My try:

**Anchor**: After processing the only string of length zero, ε, the automaton is in state $q_0$ as claimed.

**Hypothesis**: After reading a string u the automaton is in state $q_1$ iff $u=xa$, and in state $q_2$ iff $u=xab$ and in $q_0$ iff $u=ε$ or $u=xb$. The claim holds for input fragments of length up to n.

**Step**: Any string $v$ of length $n+1$ is either $v=ua$ or $v=ub$

We split to cases:

1. $v=ua$ : According to the hypothesis- if $u$ ends with $b$ then it must be either in $q_0$ or $q_2$ - there for if we call $a$ after that we get to $q_1$ so $ua$ is *not accepted*.
   Also, if $u$ ends with $a$ then it must be in $q_1$ - there for if we call $a$ after that we get to $q_1$ so $ua$ is *not accepted*.
2. $v=ub$ : According to the hypothesis- if $u$ ends with $b$ then it must be either in $q_0$ or $q_2$ - there for if we call $b$ after that we get to $q_0$ so $ub$ is *not accepted*.
   Also, if $u$ ends with $a$ then it must be in $q_1$ - there for if we call $b$ after that we get to $q_2$ so $ua$ is *accepted*.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Have you read other examples in your textbooks?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research/self-study on your own before asking, and to tell us in the question what you've tried -- what research have you done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a proof using induction on the length of the input string?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/how-do-i-write-a-proof-using-induction-on-the-length-of-the-input-string)

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755 for how to do this with a grammar (you could in principle apply those techniques if you converted the DFA to a regular grammar, though that'd be a harder path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no induction needed. There is only one transition reaching the final state $q_2$, namely $q_1 \xrightarrow{b} q_2$. Furthermore, every transition reaching $q_1$ is labelled by $a$. It follows that every word accepted by the automaton has to end by $ab$. It remains to prove that, conversely, any word of the form $uab$ is accepted. After reading $u$ from the initial state $q_0$, you reach one of the three states $q_0$, $q_1$ or $q_2$. It suffices now to observe that $q_0 \xrightarrow{ab} q_2$, $q_1 \xrightarrow{ab} q_2$ and $q_2 \xrightarrow{ab} q_2$. Thus $q_0 \xrightarrow{uab} q_2$ in all cases, which means that $uab$ is accepted.

Comment: Of course, one does not need industion, since whatever happens  with the first $n-2$ symbols is immaterial. But the OP was specific about using induction. So I tried to give it an inductive look in my answer, considering that (though not ncessary here) induxtion is often useful in other cases.

Comment: @babou I was not criticizing your answer in any way. I was just offering an alternative proof.

Answer (score 0):

The induction hypothesis can look like: "after reading a
string $u$ the automaton is in state $q_1$ iff  $P_1(u)$, and in state
$q_2$ iff $P_2(u)$."  I leave it to you to determine what are the
properties $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: $P_1(u)$ is $u=xa$ and $P_2(u)$ is $u=xb$?

Comment: @Lee This is correct for $P_1$, but you need more for $P_2$.

Comment: Well, you get to $q_2$ after you have $b$ in $q_1$ or $ab$ from $q_0$. But I guess I don't understand where I use the hypothesis for $n-1$.

Comment: @Lee Your suggestion that $P_2(u)$ is $u=xb$ is not incorrect, but it is not sufficient. You know more about the string $u$ when you reach state $q_2$.  By the way, have you been actually asked to use recursion or is it your idea to us it?

Comment: @Lee The way you use the induction hypothesis is as follow. You prove
that if the induction hypothesis is verified for all strings of length
$p$, such that $p\leq n$, then it must also be true for any string $v$
of length $n+1$. You proceed here by considering that any string $v$
of length $n+1$ is either $v=ua$ or $v=ub$, and you use the induction
hypothesis for $u$ to prove that it is also verified for $v$, in each
case.

Comment: thanks, I edited the original question and added my try for the solution. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lee Your answer is not yet quite correct. First, in the hypothsis it would
be simpler (and more accurate) to say "and in $q_0$ otherwise": note
that $u=xab$ is a special case of $u=xb$. Alternatively you could say
"and in $q_0$ iff $u=\epsilon$ or $u=b$ or $u=xbb$". Another point is
that the proof is not about acceptance, acceptance is irrelevant at
that level. What you must do is prove that the induction hypothesis is
true for $V$, and therefore for all strings by induction.

Comment: @Lee Then you
finish by noting that this property inplies that any string ending
with $ab$ will stop in state $q_2$ which is accepting.  But it would be better to leave your question as it was, and to give the answer separately, as an answer to your own question. - - - However, the answer by J.E.Pin is probably best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22246/discussion-between-lee-and-babou).